# Margin-right smaller than margin-left with equal values

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to wrap my head around responsive webdesign. In the process of this, I came across something rather oddly looking. Take the following setup:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/res/css/300-px.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/res/css/600-px.css"></link>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/res/css/desktop-px.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following CSS (from the three stylesheet-files):

```
@media (max-width:600px){
    #container {
        width:95%;
        margin-left:2.5%;
        margin-right:2.5%;
        border: 3px dashed black;
        border-radius: 25px;
        background-color:red;
        height:300px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:601px) and (max-width:900px){
    #container {
        width:90%;
        margin-left:5%;
        margin-right:5%;
        border: 3px dashed black;
        border-radius: 25px;
        background-color:green;
        height:300px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:901px){
    #container {
        width:90%;
        margin-left:5%;
        margin-right:5%;
        border: 3px dashed black;
        border-radius: 25px;
        background-color:blue;
        height:300px;
    }
}
```

The width of the container is `90%`, with margins of `5%` on either side. When rendering in my browser (both Chrome and Firefox), the margin-right appeared to be just a bit smaller than the margin-left.

The computed values shown when inspecting the element, say they are exactly the same values. Why is the actual margin-right shown on the page smaller, despite this?

I have created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/mlangendijk92/pen/WbvpZe) with the code for you to look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the 3px border you added. In the default box-model, the width of the border isn't computed in the box width so it "overflows" on the right.

To corect this, you can change the default box model behaviour by adding `box-sizing:border-box;` to `#container` so the border-width is computed in the width of the element.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/zxGZRw)**